# Flexible switch case syntax

Tags: java, switch-statement

My entire program is similar to that of command prompt. Currently, I'm writing a function that appends a word entered by a user to a particular file. The user must follow appropriate syntax. By typing in:

```
APP C Now
```

the program will append the word "Now" to the file C.

By typing in:

```
APP C She
```

the program will append the word "She" to the file C.

I have a number of choices which I've all put into a switch statement. Example:

```
case "ADD C":
case "DEL C":
```

My other cases including the two above are working perfectly fine. My question is, how would I make a switch case for this format? i.e. "APP C ***word***"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.split(" ")` on the input string to split it into an array of strings where each element in the array was a word in your original string. In other words

```
"ADD C She".split(" ") = {"ADD", "C", "She"}
```

Once you have an array you can easily check element 1 for the command name with a switch statement, element 2 for the file name, and element 3 for the argument.

Comment: Thanks but what would the case choice be?

Comment: Like this:
String[] inputSplit = input.split(" ");
if (inputSplit.equals("ADD") {
//etc

Answer (score 1):

It's typically preferable to use a lookup table and polymorphism instead of a conditional (`if` or `switch`) when practical. It's particularly helpful in a case like this, where your different commands are likely to take differing numbers of arguments, and you might even want whitespace to be significant.

You can define an interface for your commands:

```
interface Command {
    void execute(String args);
}
```

Then in your main class, you'll have a `Map<String, Command> commands`. Split the input into two parts and pass the second part to your Command:

```
String commandName = scanner.next();
String args = scanner.nextLine();
commands.get(commandName).execute(args);
```

This has the advantage of making your loop dramatically simpler than if you tried to handle all of the cases inline. It's also easier to extend, by adding new Commands (or aliases to existing ones), and easier to test, because the Commands are self-contained and can be verified independently. If you have repeated behavior, such as opening a file named in the `args`, you could even use an abstract class to share that behavior.